# Something about array and file processing

Tags: java, arrays, file

I am a java beginner...
Now I am writing a program which, when you input a number k, it shows the name of the kth image in the folder "Image".
But now when I input any number, the result would always be null.

I need some help;(

Here is my code:

```
public class Main {
    //create array, total length is number of images in file "Image"
    static int length = (new File("/Users/Sam/Desktop/Image").listFiles().length)-1;
    static String[] myArray = new String[length];   

    public static void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
    //put every file name into the array    
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
         int i = 0;
            myArray[i] = fileEntry.getName();           
        i++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final File folder = new File("/Users/Sam/Desktop/Image");
        listFilesForFolder(folder);

    //input a number x
        Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choose a frame: ");

        int a=k.nextInt();
    //show the xth image's name
        System.out.println(myArray[a]);     
        k.close();      
    }

}
```

Comment: Try doing some debugging,  Print out the value of length and the array returned by folder.listFiles(). You said: "it shows the name of the kth image in the folder "Image".  But now ... " What did you change to make the code fail now after it used to work?

Comment: `myArray = folder.listFiles()`?  Then simply use `myArray[a].getName()` instead?

Comment: move int i=0 to outside the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you intend `i` to be incremented so that `myArray` gets filled with the names:

```
public static void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
//put every file name into the array    
    int i = 0;  // Declare outside the loop.
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        myArray[i] = fileEntry.getName();           
    i++;
    }
}
```

Mind you, this will give an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, because you've initialized `myArray` to have one element too few:

```
static int length = (new File("/Users/Sam/Desktop/Image").listFiles().length)-1;
```

You don't really want to use an array for this, since arrays have a fixed size. A List (e.g. ArrayList) would be a much better fit, and you wouldn't need to worry about indices and lengths:

```
static List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

public static void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
//put every file name into the list
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        myList.add(fileEntry.getName());           
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I have never used Lists before, but after I went through some documentations this actually works better than array! Thank you very much xP

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code (I have tested it). There are two main points:

1. Move the `int i = 0;` before the for loop, to avoid setting i to 0 in every loop.
2. Remove the "-1" while declaring `length`, which is not correct and will create ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

   ```
   public class Main {
       // create array, total length is number of images in file "Image"
       static int length = (new File("/Users/Sam/Desktop/Image").listFiles().length);
       static String[] myArray = new String[length];

       public static void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
           // put every file name into the array
           int i = 0;
           for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
               myArray[i] = fileEntry.getName();
               i++;
           }
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           final File folder = new File("/Users/Sam/Desktop/Image");
           listFilesForFolder(folder);

           // input a number x
           Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Choose a frame: ");

           int a = k.nextInt();
           // show the xth image's name
           System.out.println(myArray[a]);
           k.close();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Please add an explanation why it works (and what the differences are). Otherwise the answer might be useless for learning or new users that have a similar problem.

Comment: @PinkieSwirl Thanks for reminding! I have added the explanations!

Comment: No problem :) Now `myArray[a]` might still cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` since a is not check to be `>= 0` and `< myArray.length` (but maybe that is ok if correct input can be assumed) and the formatting is a bit off.

Comment: @PinkieSwirl Yes you are absolutely right! I adjusted the format, and maybe SamW could try to add some code to check the array size? :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helps me ;)